# Troubles w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used BeautifulSoup to scrap this web https://www.rava.com/perfil/CEDEARAAPL but recently they change the source code and I´m having troubles to find the marker for the download button shown on the image attached.

I´ve tried changing attributes and markers with soup.findall with no luck.

Any help ´ll be appreciated. Thanks,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.rava.com/perfil/CEDEARAAPL'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

main_links = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'download'})

print(main_links)
[]
```

[download button web inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoYXj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is retrieved from an API source - you can find it in Network tab, when you click on that 'get excel' button. This is the way to retrieve the data and put it into a dataframe, which can be easily exported to csv, if that's what you want.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = {'access_token':'5c51a8eef05c13657876d39fc3f8acbb197c57f3',
        'especie':'CEDEARAAPL',
        'fecha_inicio':'0000-00-00',
        'fecha_fin':'2022-07-21'}

r = requests.post('https://clasico.rava.com/lib/restapi/v3/publico/cotizaciones/historicos', data=data)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['body'])
df.to_csv('the_data_needed.csv')
df
```

Response: 2598 rows × 8 columns

```
    especie fecha   apertura    maximo  minimo  cierre  volumen timestamp
0   CEDEARAAPL  2011-06-27  5.15357 5.15357 5.15357 5.15357 6720    1309143600
1   CEDEARAAPL  2011-06-29  5.11250 5.11250 5.11250 5.11250 35280   1309316400
2   CEDEARAAPL  2011-07-01  5.17857 5.17857 5.17857 5.17857 1680    1309489200
3   CEDEARAAPL  2011-07-21  5.84821 5.84821 5.82142 5.82142 38640   1311217200
4   CEDEARAAPL  2011-07-22  5.95535 5.95535 5.95535 5.95535 1400    1311303600
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... .
```

Answer (score 1):

If `access_token` changes you can use next example to get it and load the data to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rava.com/perfil/CEDEARAAPL"
api_url = (
    "https://clasico.rava.com/lib/restapi/v3/publico/cotizaciones/historicos"
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
access_token = soup.find("navbar-c")[":access_token"].strip("'")

payload = {
    "access_token": access_token,
    "especie": "CEDEARAAPL",
    "fecha_inicio": "0000-00-00",
    "fecha_fin": "2022-07-22",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()["body"])
print(df.head(5).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| especie | fecha | apertura | maximo | minimo | cierre | volumen | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CEDEARAAPL | 2011-06-27 | 5.15357 | 5.15357 | 5.15357 | 5.15357 | 6720 | 1309143600 |
| CEDEARAAPL | 2011-06-29 | 5.1125 | 5.1125 | 5.1125 | 5.1125 | 35280 | 1309316400 |
| CEDEARAAPL | 2011-07-01 | 5.17857 | 5.17857 | 5.17857 | 5.17857 | 1680 | 1309489200 |
| CEDEARAAPL | 2011-07-21 | 5.84821 | 5.84821 | 5.82142 | 5.82142 | 38640 | 1311217200 |
| CEDEARAAPL | 2011-07-22 | 5.95535 | 5.95535 | 5.95535 | 5.95535 | 1400 | 1311303600 |